# Linker Errors in Xcode Project with BlinkID SDK

Tags: microblink, blinkid

Xcode version: 14.2
BlinkID SDK version: 2.18.2
-problem:
When attempting to build the Xcode project, we encounter linker errors related to the BlinkID SDK. The following undefined symbols are reported:

OBJC_CLASS$_PPBaseOverlayViewController
OBJC_CLASS$_PPBlinkInputRecognizerResult
OBJC_CLASS$_PPBlinkInputRecognizerSettings
OBJC_CLASS$_PPCameraCoordinator
OBJC_CLASS$_PPModernOcrResultOverlaySubview
OBJC_CLASS$_PPRecognizerResult
OBJC_CLASS$_PPRecognizerSettings
OBJC_CLASS$_PPRegexOcrParserFactory
OBJC_CLASS$_PPSettings
OBJC_CLASS$_PPViewControllerFactory
OBJC_CLASS$_PPVinOcrParserFactory
OBJC_METACLASS$_PPBaseOverlayViewController

These errors also persist in the sample app provided by the BlinkID SDK.

I tried with sample app of BlinkId but same issue persist.

Comment: The version of the SDK looks outdated (released more than five years ago). 
Are you encountering the same issues with the latest version (6.3.0)? https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/releases/tag/v6.3.0

Comment: I upgrade to 5.0.0 but got same issue with 5.0.0 version also

Comment: Did you try removing the old "Microblink.framework" and "Microblink.bundle" files before adding the "Microblink.xcframework" into the project? Also, make sure that you select the "Embed & Sign" option when you add the framework.